# Join using 4 tables using Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, dml

I have 4 tables in oracle database: student, country, province, district

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
student : student_id,student_name,country_id,province_id,district_id

country : country_id, country_name

province : country_id, province_id, province_name

district : country_id, province_id, district_id, district_name
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to display the following fields using join: `student_name,country_name,province_name,district_name`

Comment: It seems that you only need simple `JOIN` to do your work. Please refer to [w3school_join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp):

```
select s.student_name, c.country_name, p.province_name, d.district_name 
from student s
  join country c on s.country_id = c.country_id
  join province p on p.province_id = s.province_id
  join district d on d.district_id = s.district_id;
```

Assuming that `country_id`, `province_id` and `district_id` are primary keys in the corresponding tables.

Answer (score 0):

Consider which is your main table.
If it is Student then use the LEFT Join, To join the Tabels:

```
SELECT S.student_name,
C.country_name,
P.province_name,
D.district_name
FROM student S LEFT JOIN country C ON S.country_id=C.country_id
LEFT JOIN province P S.province_id=P.province_id 
LEFT JOIN district D S.district_id=D.district_id
```